# Python HTTP Auth failure with: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python

Using Python, I'm trying to authenticate to a web URL. But I am getting this error:

[TypeError: 'str' object is not callable](https://pastebin.com/PEvQEi44)

This is my code:

```
import requests

BASE_URL = "https://wiki.us.cworld.company.com/rest/api/content"
VIEW_URL = "https://wiki.us.cworld.company.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId="
auth = 'username:Password!' # the exclamantion is there in the actual pass
pageid = '12345678'
get_page_ancestors(auth, pageid)
def get_page_ancestors(auth, pageid):
    # Get basic page information plus the ancestors property
    url = '{base}/{pageid}?expand=ancestors'.format(
    base = BASE_URL,
    pageid = pageid)
    r = requests.get(url, auth = auth)
```

I'm using Python 3. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example of a POST request for a login-page:

```
payload = {  # Use a dictionary for request payload
    "user":"your_username",
    "pass":"your_password"
    }  # This varies on website (look at the POST requests)

 r = requests.post("example.com/login", data=payload)  # Basic login request

 if r.status_code is 200:

     print("Successful login!")

 else:

     print("Login Failed.")
```

Answer (score 1):

From the doc: https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/

You should try: `r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('username', 'Password!'))` instead of using a string.